# Creating a sphere with glowing circle on it

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a sphere with a glowing 'donut' flattened on his front face, this donut is something like a central eye.
I'm completely new to blender.

What i need is to have 2 different meshes, one for the sphere and one for the 'eye', because i then have to add the object in unity and set 2 different materials for the eye and te body.

So here is an image of how the final sphere should look.
Again, i need to be able to use different materials inside unity for the eye and the body.

[image: The mesh i'm trying to create seen from the front]

Comment: Hi and welcome. You should add some illustrations for more accuracy about what you want. As from what I read this is simply a circle on a sphere, so very basic and probably nothing you're not able to do.

Answer (score 2):

To do that:

[image]

Simply use two spheres:

- One for the body <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then *mesh>UV sphere*
- Then create a second one at the same place, and keep only the edges that make the ring

Select the other one and delete them.

Delete this:

[image]

And scale it a bit <kbd>S</kbd> to avoid the two spheres to overlap.